# ajax request to test emai

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to check if an email address exists in ajax but I have a problem with my request.
Here is the html code

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form_email" class="form_email" >
<label class="form_et">Email <span class="etoile">*</span></label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<button type="button" id="btn_valider"
onClick="
$(document).ready(function() {
var mail = $('#email').val();
function controler(form) {
var DATA = form;
DATA += 'action=checkMail';
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'ajax.php',
data: DATA,
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
}
});
}
controlEmail(mail);
});">Verify</button>
</form>
```

And my ajax.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) &&$_POST['action'] == "checkMail") {
$test = "test";
return $test;
}
```

I pass well in the success, if I make a console.log ('success'), it is displayed. But with the current code, console.log (data) returns an empty line in console.

Why does not it work?
If I change the url and add the error function, I go through the error. I do not understand what is happening

Comment: if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "checkMail") i think you have a typo here near && you need a space

Comment: Why, especially since you're using jQuery, are you putting the entire AJAX request as inline code? That is awful design.

Comment: @JayBlanchard because I’m not the only person who will work on this project and if a developer doesn’t know jquery it will be simpler like that. But I’m agree it’s awful

Answer (score 3):

`return` in PHP returns a value from a function. It does not write the value to the output stream (i.e. the HTTP response).

For that you need `echo`, `print` or similar.